# Return specific text if four other cells match one another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I want to compare text in E3, E4, E5 and E6 and if all the same return, say, "+5%" (text) to cell E15 and “+0%” otherwise.

I tried =IF(text), =COUNT(text) and some other formulas without success.

Which formula should I apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed it. It was easier than I thouhg. Here is a code:

```
=IF((E3=E4)*AND(E3=E5)*AND(E3=E6);"+5%";"+0%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be asking for code but without one cannot 'send' in Excel. You can however 'pull' so in E15 `=IF(AND(E3=E4,E3=E5,E3=E6),"+5%","")` might suit.

*Edit*

Given what now appears to be the locale setting for OP:

`=IF(AND(E3=E4;E3=E5;E3=E6);"+5%";"")`

or, to include result for FALSE (not mentioned in OP):

`=IF(AND(E3=E4;E3=E5;E3=E6);"+5%";"+0%")`

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention that I was looking for the code. Still the one you wrote down is not working either.

Comment: I finally managed to make it. Thanks for your help @pnuts. Code is:
    =IF((E3=E4)*AND(E3=E5)*AND(E3=E6);"TRUE";"FALSE")